# Count total number votes a user has gained

Tags: 7, views, rating

I am using `rate` module where users can plus or minus the articles created by an author. Now, in the profile page of the author, I want to display the `total number of votes` he/she has got from all his articles. Is there any way to do this without using db_query ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be pretty expensive to do this without writing your own query, but here is one way you could do it:

Use [`EntityFieldQuery`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21entity.inc/class/EntityFieldQuery/7) to build a list of nids created by the current author. Something like this:

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
  ->entityCondition('bundle', 'article');
  ->propertyCondition('uid', '1')
$nodes = $query->execute();
```

Then parse the nids returned into a seperate array and use that array as a criteria parameter in [`votingapi_select_votes()`](http://api.drupalize.me/api/drupal/function/votingapi_select_votes/7). Something like:

```
$votes = votingapi_select_votes('entity_id' => $nid_array);
```

I'm not 100% sure that `votingapi_select_votes()` accepts an array for the `$criteria['entity_id']` param. You might need to loop through each nid if it doesn't.